# EEPROM - write more data than it can be written

Tags: eeprom

I have a question- if I have a external EEPROM which for example can be written 500k times, but I need to write one data in EEPROM at maximum 1,5 milions times - what I can do to manage 1,5 milion writings?

Comment: if you do not use all space, you can use different location each write; 500k is the average before starting to get unpredictable results

Comment: @phoenixstudio but it is the problem that i use all of the data, what do you think about change the bits which we actually want to write or in third write we come back to the start?

Comment: try using different encoding, like the one used for CDs, it will reduce lot the number of bits you write, for example 11111 become 10000 (where you write 1 only when bits change, and 0 when the next bits does not change)

Comment: but i already use a 500k and I have to do something to wirte 3 times more than it is possible

Comment: writing 1000 instead of 1111 means you have a gain 75%